# Webpage working on firefox but not chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have made a webpage with d3.js to create a bar chart.
it runs on Firefox but not on Chrome.

This is the error I get

> d3.min.js:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/jayeshparekh/Desktop/project/story_fandom.tsv. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.Nt.i.send @ d3.min.js:1
>   d3.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null(…)

Please tell me what I can do to make it work on Chrome

Comment: Read the error. You are using the `file` protocol and your page is not supported by Chrome unless the page lives on a web server or you specify `--allow-file-access-from-files` when starting Chrome

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local

Comment: i tried doing it, the webpage still isnt running my javascript.

Comment: You tried doing what? Please give more information?